# Internet Explorer clear saved User Name

Tags: internet-explorer, history

In certain websites we receive a dialog window(from browser itselft) which asks us to enter the user name and password. I've entered a user name and I need to clear it from history. I tried lot of options and was not successful. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Not really a programming question—try Superuser.

However, if you login again using Basic Authentication and untick the ‘Remember my password’ option, then quit and reload IE, it should be gone.

Comment: I don't have 'Remember my Password' option.

Comment: You should have a ‘Remember my password’ checkbox on the Basic Authentication dialogue box. It's there for me in IE5 to IE9 and all versions in between. If it has gone missing, see eg. http://raamdev.com/internet-explorer-remember-my-password-checkbox-missing (but in that case it should not remember passwords at all).

Comment: It is not remembering the password. It is retaining the user name.

Comment: Unticking it makes it forget the username as well, for me (after restarting). Also, you can put a different username or no username/password in.

Comment: I tried the option, by default that key was not present under Internet Settings. So I added that key and restarted my system. Still that option is not coming.